# backing up my backups...what to backup?

Tags: time-machine, backup

sorry about the facetious title...

I am writing a script to backup my time machine backups in the event that my external HDD fails, and my HDD partition with the backups looks like this...

[image: mac backup folder]

My question is, is it enough to just dump the 'latest' folder to my backup drive? Does that contain 'everything' that is o my latest system or only some revision of what changed in earlier backups?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the latest backup, then yes - it is enough to just dump the latest folder to your extra backup drive.

Each of those folders (the dates) contains the full backup as it looks on that day.

Note that Time Machines saves space on the drive by using hard links to "deduplicate" the backup. This means that if you want to copy multiple dates to your extra backup drive, you'll probably want to handle hard links - otherwise the size of the backup will normally double for two days, triple for three days, etc.

Remember: If you're only copying the latest date folder to your extra backup, you will not be able to restore files that were recently deleted, but stored in the folders representing earlier dates.

Comment: ok, I am just getting around to writing the script now....Would I also need to dump the hidden folders `.RecoverySets/ .spotlight_repair/ .spotlight_temp/` into my external double backup? or is it enough to just include the latest folder?

Comment: You do not need those folders per se. The RecoverySets folder contains a backup of the recovery partition. That can easily be downloaded and installed after a restore as it contains no user-specific information. However for convenience, you could backup it as well. BTW: Please accept the answer :)

Comment: so if I dump NOTHING but the `latest` folder into my redundant backup in the cloud, Time Machine will be able to mount that folder alone and restore from it on a new machine if I was to lose both my computer and backup HDD?

Comment: No, Time Machine requires all the files. If you want to use Time Machine to restore, you'll need to backup the whole thing. However, you can do a manual restore of the folder as all the files from your computer are backed up here (excluding the recovery partition, which does not contain user-specific files).